# Prove or Disprove $(x+\frac{1}{x})^p-x^p-\frac{1}{x^p}\ge 2^p-2$

Tags: inequality

> Let $p\in \mathbb R_{\geq2}$, $x>0$, prove or disprove 
>   $$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^p-x^p-\dfrac{1}{x^p}\ge 2^p-2$$

I can prove this for positive integers $p$  because we can use 
$$\left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^p-x^p-\dfrac{1}{x^p}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{p-1}\binom{p}{i}(x^{2i-p}+x^{p-2i})\ge\sum_{i=1}^{p-1} \binom{p}{i}=2^p-2$$

But is this true for all $p\in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 2}$?

Comment: I think you are right.You have done absolutely right.

Comment: @SufaidSaleel,Thanks,How to prove it?

Comment: You are given that $p\geq 2$, which is certainly positive.

Comment: @amWhy "$p$ positive" is not sufficient. The inequality is trivially true for $p=1$ and $p=2$, but not for $1<p<2$. ;-)

Comment: Look at the first sentence in the post DrMV: "**Let $p\ge 2,p\in \mathbb R, \;x>0$**"....

Comment: If you caught that, look at my short sentence.  I did not say that just any positive p works, I said that $p\geq 2$ is given, and it happens to be positive. There is no need to consider $p\in (1, 2)$.

Comment: @prof I believe you meant to address the asker, who made the generalization to all positive $p$, not I

Comment: Reference: This appeared as problem 11369 in the June-July 2008 issue of the American Mathematical Monthly. A solution was posted in the April 2010 issue.

Comment: @wightahtl The American Mathematical Monthly is not freely available; you need to have a subscription. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will reduce the question to some known results. For positive numbers $a,b$ we define the geometric mean $G(a,b)$ and the power mean of order $s$ denoted by $M_s(a,b)$ as folows
$$G(a,b)=\sqrt{ab},\qquad M_s(a,b)=\left(\frac{a^s+b^s}{2}\right)^{1/s}$$
Now, with $a=x$, $b=1/x$, and writing $M_s$ and $G$ instead of $M_s(a,b)$ and $G(a,b)$ for simplicity, the proposed inequality takes the form
$$\frac{M_1^p-G^p}{M_p^p-G^p}\ge 2^{1-p}$$
So, this is a particular case of the more general inequality

$$\frac{M_s^p-G^p}{M_t^p-G^p}\ge 2^{p/t-p/s}$$
Which is valid for $0<s<t$, $p\ge \max(2s,2(s+t)/3)$. A detailed proof and more results on this topic can be found in the paper of Omran Kouba entitled:
"*Bounds for the ratios of differences of power means in two arguments*"

This paper can be found [here](http://dx.doi.org/10.7153/mia-17-66) or [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.1460).

Comment: Very nice solution!!

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $L^p$ norm inequality $$
(x^p +x^{-p})^{1/p} \leq x +x^{-1},\;\; p \geq 2 \geq 1,\;\; \infty > x > 0,
$$ Or, (since both sides are positive) $$
x^p +x^{-p} \leq (x +x^{-1})^p
$$ Consider, $$
L(x) :=(x +x^{-1})^p -(x^p +x^{-p}) \geq 0,
$$ Particularly, when $x=1$, $$
2^p -2 \geq 0.\quad \quad \ldots (\heartsuit)
$$ Differentiate $L(x)$, with straightforward arrangement, $$
\frac{dL(x)}{dx} = \ldots =p x^{-p-1} \big[ (x^2+1)^{p-1} (x^2-1) -(x^{2p} -1) \big].
$$ We hope that (within considered range) $$
\frac{dL(x)}{dx} \geq 0 \quad \quad \ldots (\clubsuit)
$$ We first focus on the case $x>1$. Then it amounts to show $$
(x^2+1)^{p-1} (x^2-1) \geq x^{2p} -1,\quad \quad \ldots (\spadesuit')
$$ For, if so, by $(\heartsuit)$, $(\clubsuit)$, and $(\spadesuit')$ $$
(x +x^{-1})^p -(x^p +x^{-p}) \geq 2^p -2
$$ As desired.

Come back to $(\spadesuit')$. With $$
y :=\frac{x^2-1}{2(x^2+1)} =\frac{1}{2} -\frac{1}{x^2+1}
$$ implying $$
0 <y <\frac{1}{2}
$$ (My motivation of substitution came from the desire that the whole inequality shall be written in a form with "homogeneous dimensions", and range of variables shall lie in a finite interval.)

After some completely straightforward but tedious manipulation, $(\spadesuit')$ becomes $$
1 \geq \frac{1}{2y} \left[ \left( \frac{1}{2} +y \right)^p -\left( \frac{1}{2} -y \right)^p \right]. \quad \quad \ldots (\spadesuit)
$$ 
Now, this is interpreted with the fact that, in the graph of $x^p$, a secant line lying in the very middle of $[0,1]$ has slope less than 1, which is that of the line from 0 to 1.

To show this, find $\eta_1,\eta_2$, according to mean value theorem, $$
p \eta_1^{p-1} y =\left( \frac{1}{2} +y \right)^p -\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^p,  \\
p \eta_2^{p-1} y =\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^p -\left( \frac{1}{2} -y \right)^p
$$ Thus rhs of $(\spadesuit)$ becomes (to stress dependence on $y$) $$
\frac{p}{2} (\eta_1(y)^{p-1} -\eta_2(y)^{p-1})
$$ Of course, $\eta_1(y) >\eta_2(y)$.
And observe that $\eta_1(y)$ is increasing with $y$.
Indeed, the secant line with greater $y$ must correspond to a greater $\eta_1^{p-1}$, thus a greater $\eta_1$. Similarly, $\eta_1(y)$ is decreasing with $y$.
So, rhs of $(\spadesuit)$, seen as function of $y$, is increasing too.
The maximum value is achieved when $y=1/2$, which gives 1.

The case $x=1$ is trivial, and the case $0<x<1$ can be obtained by $x \mapsto x^{-1}$ and what we just showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer which again makes use of the derivative, but in
a different fashion than in Aminopterin's answer. Let

$$L(x) = \left(x+\dfrac{1}{x}\right)^p-x^p-\dfrac{1}{x^p} - 2^p+2$$

and we want to establish that $L(x) \ge 0$. Note that $L(x=1) = 0$.

We have (see Aminopterin's answer)
$$
L'(x) = \frac{dL(x)}{dx} = p x^{-p-1} \big[ (x^2+1)^{p-1} (x^2-1) -(x^{2p} -1) \big]
$$

Now we can show that $L(x=1) = 0$ is indeed the *only* condition with *equality* in the OP's problem if we can establish that $L'(x) > 0$ for $x > 1$ and $L'(x) < 0$ for $0<x < 1$. To this end, it suffices to set $x^2 = y$ and consider

$$
f(y) =  (y+1)^{p-1} (y-1) - y^{p}+1
$$

We need to establish that $f(y) > 0$ for $y > 1$ and $f(y) < 0$ for $0<y < 1$.
Now this has been established [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389644/), which completes the proof. $\qquad \Box$